# Meteor webapp not running on safari

Tags: canvas, meteor, web-applications, safari, chart.js

Since i updated my meteor version from 1.6.0.1 to 1.7.0.3, my webapp crashes on safari. It's running fine on chrome and Firefox though.

No error is thrown neither on console nor on server.

This message is displayed on the browser screes : 'A problem repeatedly occurred with localhost:3000/urlPath'

The error is occurring because of the following line:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("Chart").getContext("2d")
```

This is written in onRendered.

HTML for the same :

```
<canvas id="Chart" width="150" height="100"></canvas>
```

Package used :

```
chart:chart
```

Comment: I think you will get the best help, when you try to create a minimal app example that allows others to reproduce your problem with this specififc version of Safari and post this issue in Meteor's github issues.

Comment: Also if this is a genuine bug, you should submit an issue on the official meteor repo: http://github.com/meteor/meteor/

Comment: Ok thanks. I am creating a  minimal app to reproduce the problem and hence submit an issue on GitHub with proper specifications.